# Selenium Webdriver : Dismiss Chrome Alert

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to select the check box `Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs` before selecting ok to close the alert

[image: Alert screenshot]

Currently i am using

```
Alert alert=driver.switchTo().alert();

//check the checkbox

alert.accept();
```

As an normal interactive user to check the check box i have to use a combination of `<Tab>` + `<Space/Enter>` keys. The `<Tab>` shifts the focus to the check-box and the `<Space/Enter>` checks the check-box.

**Solutions Tried**

I tried using Java sendKeys mechanisms ( Robot class, driver.sendKeys(), etc.), but an `UnhandledAlertException` is getting thrown.

I tried using `alert.sendKeys` which is different from `driver.sendKeys()` but it too failed

```
//check the checkbox
alert.sendKeys("\t");
alert.sendKeys("{TAB}");
alert.sendKeys("\uE004");
alert.sendKeys("\\U+0009");
alert.sendKeys(Integer.toString(KeyEvent.VK_TAB));
```

I am trying to avoid robot class as much as possible as i need to run the test in grid in which case robot class will not work.Any pointers on how to send keys to the alert window ?

Temporarily i could do it using a javascript `window.alert = function() {};` by simply overriding the alert with an empty function just curious to know if it could be done with webdriver functions like `alert.sendkeys` or any other methods ??

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Why do you want to do that.Then it wont show any alert at all for that page

Comment: @Madhan Thanks for the reply...yes i know that.. currently there is a bug in our site due to which alerts are displayed randomly on selecting some web elements it has been reported but in the mean time we are not able to run our scripts due to this issue

Comment: What's the browser you are using chrome/firefox/safari

Comment: You don't want alert at all for that page or you want some alerts to popup?

Comment: @Madhan No currently i don't need alerts in the page...

Comment: @Madhan I could do disable alert  using javascript by simply overriding the alert with an empty function [window.alert = function() {};] just curious to know if it could be done by using selenium webdriver functions like alert.sendkeys or anyother thing??

Comment: Add the js code to the question as well.